How to create an equal size window on the wall around the corner?
I am a Blender beginner.
I am attempting to recreate a building from a photo.
I have created a window on one wall (1 in the image below) and would like to have an identical one around the corner (2 in the image below). I would like it to be the same size exactly and not just an approximation. I know how to make the window itself. Not certain how to achieve equal size.

How do I achieve this? Thanks for you help!

Pretty easy to do this with a mirror modifier, using an empty as the mirror axis, with bisect turned on.

Make sure the mirror object is aligned exactly with the edge on the corner you want to mirror across. If you just used a regular bevel operator it should be exactly 45 degrees.
These are the mirror settings I used, you might need to fiddle with yours a bit.

Result:

If your building is not perfectly square then you might need to adjust the back edge to meet the mirror axis more perfectly.


Thank you.
Just to be certain, as I am quite new to this.
By "empty" you mean an empty object that has no mesh, correct? So that's the axis of the mirror.
Do I understand correctly that in your images this is placed where the 3d cursor is?
In the settings screenshot, is this also the object mentioned in the "mirror object" field, or that does that contain the geometry I am actually aiming to mirror around the corner?
Thanks again!

Correct, that is what/where the empty object is. You can use any object to mirror this way, but an empty is easiest.
